# Changing Variable at the command line of a bash script

Tags: shell-script

I have the following bash script that I can't edit (there are too many):

```
#! /bin/bash/
#filename: testbash
# User specific aliases and functions
test="test1"
echo $test
```

Is it possible to run testbash as source with the test variable changed?
ie:

```
>> . testbash
test1
>> . testbash -someargument(test="newtest")
newtest
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand the questions, but I think this is what you are looking for.

example

```
[root@HomeTraining ~]$ cat example 
#!/bin/bash
VAR1=$1
echo "$VAR1"
```

Where $1 is the first argument in your command.

```
[root@HomeTraining ~]$ . example New_Text
New_Text
```

I think you can do as many as you want.

```
#!/bin/bash
VAR1=$1
VAR2=$2
echo "$VAR1 $VAR2"

$ . example one two
one two
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't make the script see another value for `$test` than `test1`, given the way that your script is currently written (it assigns the string `test1` to the variable unconditionally, then prints it).  Sourcing the script would not help. The only thing sourcing the script would do is to set the variable `test` to `test1` in the current environment, regardless of its previous value.

---

You could make your script have a *default value* that is overridden by giving the script a command line argument.

In the simplest case, this may look like

```sh
#!/bin/sh

value=${1:-test1}
printf 'value is %s\n' "$value"
```

I'm avoiding to use the name `test` for the variable, as that is also the name of a standard utility. Not that it causes issues, but it makes the code less ambiguous to read. I'm also using `/bin/sh` rather than `bash` in the `#!`-line since the script does not use any `bash`-specific features.  It would still be executable by `bash` though, and by `ksh`, `yash`, `zsh` and any other POSIX shell.

This would set the value of the variable `value` to whatever the first command line argument was, unless it was not provided, in which case it is set to the string `test1`.  The `${parameter:-word}` is a standard parameter substitution that is expanded to `word` if `$parameter` is an empty string or if that variable is unset.

Testing:

```
$ ./script.sh
value is test1
```

```
$ ./script.sh hello
value is hello
```

Allowing the script to take an option, `-v`, that takes a single option-argument:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

value=test1

while getopts 'v:' opt; do
    case $opt in
        v) value=$OPTARG ;;
        *) echo 'error in command line parsing' >&2
           exit 1
    esac
done

# not needed if you're not expecting operands after the options
# on the command line:
shift "$(( OPTIND - 1 ))"

printf 'value is %s\n' "$value"
```

Testing that last script:

```
$ ./script.sh
value is test1
```

```
$ ./script.sh -v hello
value is hello
```